# Laravel reduce loading time of 50k rows belongTo count query

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, optimization

I got the following query that takes ~4 seconds and i don't know how to optimize it anymore, maybe someone can help.

```
Model::all()->where('belongsToClass.active', 1)->count();
```

The long loading time comes from the where belongsToClass check. Without it, the count is instant.
Data size: 50k rows of data in the Model ; 400 rows of data in the belongsToClass

The server can't be the problem and i used foreign keys / index on the model/belongsto table.

Comment: This video help a lot of you. It would be difficult to explain it here.-> [watch this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HadES55O4Wk)

Comment: Thank you for the video, it helped for understanding the problem better.

Comment: 50K is going to grow, based on what you are using the count for, you can opt for caching the count, especially if it's for displaying purposes.

Comment: Please provide the generated SQL.  And what indexes exist on the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Model::all()` will retrieve all the records of that model (in a collection), after that you use the `->where()` which walks through the whole collection. Instead use the `->whereHas` on the Model itself:

```php
Model::whereHas('belongsToClass', function($query) {
    $query->where('active', 1)
})->count();
```

be sure to read the docs, https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence

they explain it in a better way than I do.

Comment: I get your point and i was using the way you wrote in other situations, but here is the join missing / 'belongsToClass.active' doesn't work in that case. What would be the solution for that? I tried the following but the with is beeing skipped: Model::with('belongsToClass')->where('belongsToClass.active', 1)->count(); The result is: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'belongsToClass.active' in 'where clause' (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `Model` where `belongsToClass`.`active` = 1)

Comment: You need to use whereIn if it’s a value from the relationship

Comment: whereIn doesnt seem right here. I got it working this way, but i would like it to be working with "with" since its an belongsTo Model and i dont want to use the join like that. "Model::leftJoin('belongsToClass', 'model.id', '=', 'belongsToClass.id')->where('belongsToClass.active', 1)->count());"

Comment: @DappFuture i didnt get the point, i adjusted my answer